# Simulate Upload in Chrome Postman WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to simulate a FileUpload with Chrome Postman to my ASP.NET WebApi method . To do this I perform the following steps in Postman.

1.Open postman and choose POST method from address bar.
2.Enter valid URL.
3.Go to Body section below address bar.
4.From Body section choose Binary option. 
5.Hit the "Chose Files" button to select a file to upload.
6.Choose a file
7.Ensure the "Post" option is selected
8.Hit "Send"

I then test for MultiPartContent, however when I step through my method the Request Object doesn't appear to have the info that I need . The exception below will get hit.

```
public List<Premium.Model.BureauModUpdate> Post() {
        HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
        if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
```

}

It doesn't appear as if any info concerning the file upload is in the request. A review of the request content yields this:

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost/WCAPI/Lookup/BureauModUpdate/CreateNyModUpdates', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Connection: keep-alive
  Accept: */*
  Accept-Encoding: gzip
  Accept-Encoding: deflate
  Accept-Encoding: br
  Accept-Language: en-US
  Accept-Language: en; q=0.8
  Host: localhost
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
  User-Agent: (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
  User-Agent: AppleWebKit/537.36
  User-Agent: (KHTML, like Gecko)
  User-Agent: Chrome/55.0.2883.87
  User-Agent: Safari/537.36
  Postman-Token: 23f64855-3b60-3f87-3aa1-ba7d0a841273
  Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
  Content-Length: 200284
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
}}
```

Is there something else I need to be doing ? If anybody has any suggestions or can point me in the right direction on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your content type is incorrect. It should be `multipart/form-data` when uploading files.

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is used only when posting a form with no binary data.